# No such function: sqlcipher_export()

Tags: sqlite, sqlcipher

i using start terminal

```
-macbook:sqlTest user1$ sqlite3 sqlTest.sqlite
SQLite version 3.7.13 2012-07-17 17:46:21
Enter ".help" for instructions
Enter SQL statements terminated with a ";"
sqlite> ATTACH DATABASE 'encrypted.sqlite' AS encrypted KEY 'testkey';
sqlite> SELECT sqlcipher_export('encrypted');
Error: no such function: sqlcipher_export
sqlite>
```

what makes no such function: sqlcipher_export?

Answer (score 3):

As answered on the mailing list:

The first step is to build the sqlcipher command line tool, as described here:

http://sqlcipher.net/introduction/

Once you have done this, you should run the command like this:

```
$ ./sqlcipher sqlTest.sqlite
```

or

```
$ /full/path/to/sqlcipher/sqlcipher sqlTest.sqlite
```

On unix systems, if you don't provide an explicit path for a command, the system will look for the program in $PATH. On OSX, the system ships with a sqlite3 command, so you've probably been using that instead of the version compiled with SQLCipher. Please let us know if that resolves the problem. Thanks!

Comment: Thank u for help, sqlTest.sqlite size is 1 MB, has contain 4 tables. 
./sqlcipher plaintext.sqlite
QLCipher version 3.8.0.2 2013-09-03 17:11:13
Enter ".help" for instructions
Enter SQL statements terminated with a ";"
sqlite> ATTACH DATABASE 'encrypted.sqlite' AS encrypted KEY 'testkey';
sqlite> SELECT sqlcipher_export('encrypted');
sqlite> DETACH DATABASE encrypted;
After command above,
plaintext.sqlite file size is getting zero byte and encrypted.sqlite getting 1 KB.
After Decrypt to plaintext
plaintext.sqlite size is zero byte. contain tables are missing.

Comment: As noted by Nick on the mailing list: When you perform a sqlcipher_export command on an attached database, it
does not delete the referenced database.  Also, in your example below,
once you have exported a plain-text database to an encrypted form, you
will not be able to open it with the standard sqlite3 command line
shell, nor would you have access to the sqlcipher_export convenience
function.  To verify you are using a SQLCipher command line shell, issue
PRAGMA cipher_version and verify you get a value printed on your screen.